# Is it possible to expand a gap buffer without copying data?

Tags: text, memory-management, data-structures, virtual-address-space, page-tables

I was reading [this overview](https://www.cs.unm.edu/~crowley/papers/sds.pdf) of some possible data structures for storing a sequence of characters for the purposes of a text editor. One popular and efficient way is the [gap buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gap_buffer).

When the gap buffer fills up so that there is no longer a gap, the data would need to be copied into the beginning and end of a larger buffer to recreate a gap for further insertion. However, on page 9 of the overview, it states that

> with some help from the operating system, we can expand the gap without actually moving any data.

I haven't been able to figure out a way to do that, so I'm wondering if is really possible. And if so, how it could be done and in which cases. Or am I misunderstanding what the author meant?

Comment: Memory mappings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Linux you can use e.g. [mremap()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mremap.2.html) to move data in the virtual address space.

As for Windows, you should use a combination of [AllocateUserPhysicalPages()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-allocateuserphysicalpages), [MapUserPhysicalPages()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-mapuserphysicalpages), [VirtualAlloc()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualalloc) and thereabouts.

The whole idea is that instead of copying the data you're changing the how/where physical memory (with the data) appears in the address space. If you aren't familiar with the related concepts, read up on page translation and page tables.

Update: Strictly speaking you may still end up copying up to a page size worth of data when the gap disappears and the cursor position is near the beginning of a memory page. But that should be hardly noticeable on modern systems. You still don't copy the data in all the other pages.

Comment: I'm not sure how this applies when the gap we need to create is located in the middle of a memory page, as it would be in most cases. We can easily relocate the rest of the pages that only contain "pre" and "post" gap data to the beginning and end of a different or the same extended virtual address space. But don't we need to manually copy all of the "post" data from the "gap" page to its new location. Is that operation considered cheap enough to ignore the cost of when we're dealing with a sufficient number of pages, since it will never be more than a page size?

Comment: In other words, my understanding is that the need to copy _some_ data is unavoidable, up to a page size, unless the gap is exactly at the boundary between two pages. But apart from that special case, isn't it impossible to expand the gap buffer "without actually moving _any_ data"? If that's indeed the case, the author's statement would be technically wrong.